# Can I Configure a default window layout for the XAML code/designer window in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to configure a default layout for the VS XAML code/designer window? I.e. same split mode (vertical vs. horizontal) and same split ratio (e.g. 80:20).

I want to only have to set up the window how I like once, not all the time.
It seems like VS tries to be smart and save the look for each .xaml file.

I know about Tools/Options/XAML-Designer, it does not solve this particular problem.

Comment: *"If there is no way, well so be it..."* => There is always the option to write an extension to solve that ;o)